# The location of a database which is created by entity framework automatically

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I have been using Entity framework recently and my WPF application totally works fine although i have a little problem. Despite it stores and retrieves data, i can not see or find the data base which has been created by the framework. When i start SqlServer management studio there is no new data base there. I also searched this path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA" but i couldn't find it. Another odd thing is that i didn't put any connection string inside the config file but as i said, it stores data somewhere in an anonymous data base.
Would you mind telling me where exactly the data base is ? 
I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2008R2.

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: That could be a localdb. Check your %UserProfile% folder or \App_Data. If it created a SQL Express DB it will be in the .\SQLEXPRESS instance. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/

Comment: standard database folder is connection string as database name in the path of the executing assembly. I don't think you can go entirely without a connection string.

Comment: Oddly I do recall you can go without a connection string. EF has flipped with how it handles that (SQL Express vs localdb). http://david.gardiner.net.au/2015/04/entity-framework-6-connection-string.html

Answer (score 0):

Work with **connection string** in web.config.

Example:

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AnyName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb);Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**In your context**

```
public Context()
        : base("AnyName")
    {}
```

The name (**"AnyName"**) must be the same in context and connectionstring.

Hope it's useful!